# How can I fix my code to accept a basic number input the first time, not the second time?

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to make a simple code for homework where I take some input from the user and use a for-loop to count down by 2 until it reaches 0.

I could do this part, but for some reason when I input a number it wont do anything until I input another number. I don't know why the first number is ignored, and would appreciate some help

(Also, I can only give a wrong input once and I don't know how to make it accept multiple wrong inputs without breaking. If anyone knows how to fix that too I would appreciate it)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountDownByTwos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input a positive number and I will count down by 2");
        //validation
        if(!in.hasNextDouble()) {
            String input = in.next();
                System.err.println(input+" is not a number, try again please");
        }
        if(in.nextDouble() < 0) {
                System.err.println("Please input a POSITIVE number next time");
        }
        //catch the proper input
        double num = in.nextDouble();
        //for statement with all the stuff in it
        for(double i = num; i >= 0; i = i-2) {
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the validation to while loops and if-else ones, but those just added more errors. I think the hiccup comes from the validation, but it just randomly didn't accept the first correct input and refused to stop doing that, so idk.

I know this is very simple code, but I just cannot figure out how to fix this and need some help.

Comment: You have two `in.nextDouble()` calls.  Each one of those needs to read a number.  You need to fetch the value ONCE into a variable, then test the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing arises from the fact that when you're using methods like `nextDouble()`, you're actually consuming input. Each time you call this method, the scanner will read from the input source.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountDownByTwos {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input a positive number and I will count down by 2");

        // Keep prompting the user until a valid input is provided
        double num = -1; // initialized to a negative number to ensure the loop runs at least once
        while (num < 0) {
            if (!in.hasNextDouble()) {
                String input = in.next();
                System.err.println(input + " is not a number, try again please");
            } else {
                num = in.nextDouble();
                if (num < 0) {
                    System.err.println("Please input a POSITIVE number.");
                    num = -1; // reset it to a negative value so the loop will continue
                }
            }
        }

        // for statement to count down
        for (double i = num; i >= 0; i = i - 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `hasNextDouble()` does not consume input. Of these two, only `nextDouble()` does.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two inputs because you are calling in.nextDouble() twice, once when checking if it is negative, and once when declaring the num variable.

This code worked for me: `

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountDownByTwos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input a positive number and I will count down by 2");

        //our number used for input
        double num = 0;

        boolean isNum = false;

        //getting input while their input is not a number
        while(!isNum) {
            //trying to get a double input, if not double it is caught
            try {
                //getting the input
                num = in.nextDouble();
                isNum = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //if input was caught
                String input = in.nextLine();
                System.err.println(input + " is not a number, try again please");
                //going to the start of the loop again
                continue;
            }
            //if the try catch succeeded
            if(num < 0){
                //making isNum false so we start the loop again
                isNum = false;
                System.err.println("Please input a POSITIVE number next time");
            }
        }

        for (double i = num; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is due to the way you structured your code. The `hasNextDouble()` and `nextDouble()` methods of the Scanner class should be used together to ensure proper input reading. In your current code, you're calling `in.nextDouble()` multiple times without re-prompting the user for input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountDownByTwos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double num = 0; // Initialize num
        
        // Get a valid positive number from the user
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Input a positive number and I will count down by 2");
            
            if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
                num = in.nextDouble();
                if (num >= 0) {
                    break; // Break the loop if a valid positive number is provided
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Please input a POSITIVE number");
                }
            } else {
                String input = in.next();
                System.err.println(input + " is not a number, try again please");
            }
        }
        
        // Use a for loop to count down by 2 until it reaches 0
        for (double i = num; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code:

1. We initialize `num` to `0` outside the loop to ensure it's defined before being used.
2. We use a `while` loop to repeatedly prompt the user for input until a valid positive number is provided.
3. Inside the loop, we use `hasNextDouble()` to check if the next input is a double. If it is, we then check if it's greater than or equal to `0`. If both conditions are met, we break out of the loop. If not, we display an error message.
4. If the input is not a valid double, we display an error message and continue the loop.
5. Once a valid positive number is obtained, we use a `for` loop to count down by 2 until it reaches `0`.